# redirect old URL to new URL [codeigniter .htaccess]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

My old website had trouble so I code a new one.
But I cant redirect my old URL to new URL.
My old URL looks like :

```
http://sample.com/?m=news&e=view&id=66
```

It already shared and SEO on google. But I completed remove old source in my host.
I want when someone click in that link, it will redirect to my new page:

```
http://sample.com/en/news/redirect-url-66.html
```

But idk how to write Rule for htaccess.Can anyone tell me what should I do.
This's my htaccess (default CodeIgniter htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

old url:

```
http://sample.com/?m=news&e=view&id=66
```

new url:

```
http://sample.com/index.php/en/news/redirect-url-66.html
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} m=([a-z]+) $1
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} e=(view) $2
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) $3 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/en/%1/redirect-url-%3.html?
```

Hope that works for you

Comment: Sorry sir, I forgot edit my post. My new URL i want to redirect is : http://sample.com/en/news/redirect-url-66.html

Comment: Internal Server Error sir. When I tried your code, all my link, including my homepage: http://sample.com are error.  I only want redirect just 1 link http://sample.com/?m=news&e=view&id=66 to http://sample.com/en/news/redirect-url-66.html , not all of links, other links in my new site still use http://sample.com/en/news/alias-id.html. I also tried use controller to redirect . But I cant named controller = ?m=news&e=view&id=66.

Comment: i didnt work, when i click to  http://sample.com/?m=news&e=view&id=66 , it redirect to homepage http://sample.com . I think the problem is the old URL had "?" character from the start.

Comment: I tried, It doesnt work with codeigniter. URL always  identify the "?" character after site url is a command mean like active default_controller => redirect to homepage. >.<

Comment: in codeigniter the uri is in this order : controller/method/parameter
so in your case en/news/redirect-url-66.html  is parsed like this : "en" is the controller, "news" is the method and "redirect-url-66.html" is the parameter, I am not sure I understood your last comment, but this is how ci works

Answer (score 0):

are you using WordPress ? because if you do there are plenty of plugins that can help you with automatic Redirects at the server-level without you needing to do all the redirects yourself which with big sites can be a pain in the butt...